# Snowflake SQL minus returns records even if the same VIEW is substracted from itself

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running the following query in Snowflake:

```
SELECT * FROM "USER_HOME"."SAQIB_ALI"."TEST_VIEW"
minus
SELECT * FROM "USER_HOME"."SAQIB_ALI"."TEST_VIEW";
```

This should not return any results. However I am getting back few records. Why is that?

Comment: I tried with same table at my end , it is working as expected What is structure of your table and do you have variant data.

Comment: @Anand The VIEWs have a fairly simple structure. And there is not variant columns in them. Even if they had VARIANT columns, it still should not produce any differences, right?

Comment: are they materialized views? thus the two reads are getting different data.. or do they have a `SEQx()` or anything generated?

Comment: can you please list the DDL for the view, because `minus` works of static data, thus for it not to be working implies there is something transitive in the data returned by your view.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim, I don't have SEQ or anything that will make the VIEW non-deterministic.

Comment: Then it sounds like a bug, and I'd open a support ticket. But the DDL would be interesting.

Comment: Hi can you do a MINUS column by column and identify which column it gives you the data and any idea how many rows it it is returning  ( is it returning only some rows or the complete table.?

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I have opened up a ticket with Snowflake.

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal it is only returning a small fraction (0.04%) of rows. And it is different rows each time.

Comment: Is the view based on one table or multiple ? Can you identify which column you get the difference ?  Try putting  a TRIM around the column and see if you still get difference.

Comment: that last point makes it same even more, your data. But do you have any `ORDER BY <float>` because float/doubles are not stable. OR if you sum floating point numbers and order by that, and the prune. That can be the source of trouble.

Comment: Last idea, it seem you are very uncomfortable about sharing your DDL, so make new veiws, and slow have less and less columns in them, until they become stable. Find the data type causing the problem, then update the ticket, with just that, and we might be able to explain why that happens.

Comment: Thank you all for all the suggestions. This was very helpful. Turns out LISTAGG is nondeterministic. And that was root case of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that this was caused due to nondeterministic nature of `LISTAGG`. `LISTAGG` can be made deterministic by using the `ORDER BY` as follows:

```
select listagg(distinct o_orderkey) within group (order by o_orderkey) ...;
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing the answer up - it would have helped a lot if we had the SQL for the view!